# How to create countdown timer associate with praytimes.js

Tags: javascript, time, countdown, countdowntimer, jquery-countdown

i am using praytimes.org to perform prayer times, how to create countdown to the time when the prayer is coming, and so on, and so on... im using 24h format

eg: `x minutes y seconds before fajr` after that `x minutes y seconds before sunrise` ...

[image]

Please help, thank you!

Comment: hello, did u find an answer to your question. I have the same issue but with the java class

Comment: @Abood no i didn't